# Unable to open a Linux SMB share from the domain controller

Tags: linux, windows, windows-server-2003, server-message-block

I am trying to access the SMB share which resides on one of my linux development servers, whether I type \\servername or \\192.168.0.100 (it's ip), I get asked for the username/password and then it gives the error:

"\\servername not accessible. You might not have premission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.

The specified network name is no longer available"

I am able to access this from my workstation or another Windows Server 2003, but not from either of our domain controllers (also Windows Server 2003)

Comment: What's in the logs on the Windows server and the Linux servers?

Comment: nothing in the Windows logs (far as I can see), and nothing in the smb log, far as I can see- useful eh?

Comment: Have you verified connectivity between the Windows server and the Linux server?  If there's nothing in the Linux server's log, the issue is likely to be isolated to the Windows server.  Can you connect to other CIFS shares from the Windows server?

Comment: I can ping from the Domain Controller > The Linux server on which the share resides. It also prompts for a username/password (like it should), but its after this step it errors.

Answer (score 1):

Check your local security policy (secpol.msc) isn't trying to force you to use NTLMv2;

Change these settings;

**- Microsoft network client: Digitally sign communications (always)** : Disabled

**- Network security: LAN Manager authentication level** : Send NTLM response Only

- **Network security: Minimum session security for NTLM SSP based (including secure RPC) clients** : No Minimum
- **Network security: Minimum session security for NTLM SSP based (including secure RPC) servers** : No Minimum

Cheers,

Jon

Answer (score 0):

- Check the join to the domain.

  net ads testjoin
- Are the domain controller(s) and the Samba box in the *same* domain?  If not, how do you have it joined?
- What is the security level set for in Samba?
- What are your security settings for `server signing` and `client use spnego` set for?
- Is Kerberos using the correct ticket format?  [Sometimes it helps to specify the encryption type used](http://mailman.mit.edu/pipermail/kerberos/2004-June/005543.html).
- Are there Kerberos definitions for all of the forests in your enterprise?  If your Samba box lives in a forest separate from the domain controllers it may not know how to "get there from here".

Comment: Hi Avery- thanks for the reply, I will work through these suggestions/steps shortly.